# resize image in view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My style code is as follows:

```
advertiseBox:{
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  },
  advertiseImage:{
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 7,
  },
```

Calling the image and style is as follows:

```
<View style={[todayStyles.advertiseBox, {backgroundColor: 'blue'}]}>

  <Image source={require('../../assets/images/advertise.png')} style={todayStyles.advertiseImage}/>

</View>
```

In the code it is clear that margin and padding are not used. Why the image has been distance from the top and bottom and right. What is the solution to the problem?

[image]

Comment: How about setting the view size to 200,300 and setting the image height and width to undefined?

Comment: @Yossi thanks, I removed the width and height but did not change

Comment: Try putting width: "100%" and removing the height attribute.

Comment: @ViniciusZomer not work

Comment: remove row-reverse for row and remove flex-start

Comment: here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemethod

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21301), it seems that resizeMode is not working for PNG in version 0.57 of React Native

Answer (score 0):

```
advertiseBox:{
  justifyContent:"flex-start",
},
advertiseImage:{
  //resizeMode: 'cover', 
  height: 200,
  width: 300,
  borderRadius: 7,
},
```